# Not clear where to add --conf spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4 in aws cloudformation yaml template

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I have created glue job for converting avro files into parquet. For that I am importing

```
--conf spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4
```

in yaml file. But still job is failing as dataframes are not getting created . 
The following error is shown : AnalysisException('Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.avro. Avro is built-in but external data source module since Spark 2.4.')

My yml template is as follows:

```
 DefaultArguments:
    '--job-language': 'python'
    '--job-bookmark-option': 'job-bookmark-disable'
    '--enable-metrics': ''
    '--conf': 'spark.executor.memoryOverhead=1g --conf spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem=2g --conf spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4'
    '--JOB_NAME': !If [IsPythonShell, !Ref GlueJobName, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
```

I am unclear where i am going wrong. My guess is i am putting the conf package at wrong place.

Please help.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: @BiplobBiswas have a look at my comment under the Frederic's answer

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this would be to use `--extra-jars` ([Documentation on github](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-glue-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.md)) and reference the jar file in S3. You would have to store the jar in S3 of course. I don't think Glue will download any jars as a normal spark-submit would.

Comment: have you already tried this before? I did it the way that you suggested but got this exception `An error occurred while calling o84.csv.org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat could not be instantiated`

Comment: I just succeeded with this. However, spark avro 2.12-2.4.3 still did not work, but avro 2.11-2.4.4 worked.

Answer (score 0):

Also add to the glue job `--user-jars-first: "true"` parameter.